# Get text from other site to use in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I searched but couldn't find a working solution, so I wanted to ask: How can I get text from another site to display on my site? Basically I want the exchange rate from this site: https://www.coingecko.com/de/kurs_chart/bitcoin/usd
(Right now it's 3.399,95474781 $    ) I want to find that number without the $ so I can display the actual exchange rate whenever the site changes it so it automatically changes on my site as well. How could I do it? would file_get_contents do the work? Or is there a better approach to search for the exact text?

Comment: `would file_get_contents do the work?` sound like the right PHP function to use

Comment: have you tried CURL?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need an Application Programming Interface (API), which is a way for a system to allow you to place a request for data. When a system exposes an API, and you send a request for data, it will return (probably asynchronously), and you can go ahead and use that data (e.g. modify text on your site).

You can just look for an API for coinGecko; better is to do a search for an API for the actual data that you need, e.g. API bitcoin exchange rate.

If you're using jquery on your site, I recommend ajax for handling the asynchronous data requests and the $('#'+thisId).html('set text here') type function for modifying the text in a div with id = thisId.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to store the number. You can just use JavaScript to accomplish this job.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('https://www.coingecko.com/de/kurs_chart/bitcoin/usd');
xhr.addEventListen('load', function(){
    var response = xhr.responseText;
    // serch the number and inject to your html
});
xhr.send();
```